# Creating send email button

Tags: php, html, forms, kohana

I have some old code made in kohana framework. Need to create "send test email" function activated after clicking "send" button. Have no idea hot to make this. The test email should contain data from email subject, content fields and be send to inputed email address.

```
<div class="block">
    <h3 class="orange">Email setup:</h3>
    <div class="form_row">

        <div>
            <label class="short">Email subject:</label>
            <?php echo Form::input('email_subject', $data['email_subject'], array('maxlength' => '100')) ?>
            <?php echo Html::image('img/help.gif', array('class' => 'help', 'width' => 13, 'height' => 13, 'title' => 'Some title, doesn't matter')) ?>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label class="textarea-label">Email content:</label>
            <?php echo Html::image('img/help.gif', array('class' => 'help', 'width' => 13, 'height' => 13, 'title' => 'Some title, doesn't matter')) ?>
            <?php echo Form::textarea('email_body', $data['email_body'], array('id' => 'textarea1')) ?>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label class="short">test email address field:</label>
            <?php echo Form::input('test_email', '' ,array('maxlength' => '50')) ?>
            <?php echo Html::image('img/help.gif', array('class' => 'help', 'width' => 13, 'height' => 13, 'title' => 'BCC address')) ?>
        </div>

        <div>
            <?php if(Auth::instance()->get_user()->username != 'some_user') echo Form::submit('save', 'Save') ?>
            <?php if(Auth::instance()->get_user()->username != 'some_user') echo Form::submit('send', 'Send test email') ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no other option than send an email by the server. Ko7 recommends https://github.com/svenbw/kohana-email. And do not put sending in view, but in `APPATH/classes/Controller/Somecontroller.php` BTW: Did you try upgrade to php7? (Kohana-> ko7)

Answer (score 0):

You can use form

```php
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<button name="btn_send">Send Email</button>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["btn_send"])) {
    //Sending email code
}
?>
```